# Chrome Extension that recognizes a URL and transforms it to a link

Tags: google-chrome, browser-addons, url

I'm looking for an Chrome Extension that recognizes URLs on a Webpage that are plain text and transform it to a real link.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Clickable Links](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/mgamelhnfokapndfdodnmfiningckjia) is the extension you're looking for.

[image]

Comment: It only seems to work on remote pages and not local pages. I tested it on a quick test.html on my local machine, it failed. But then I tested it on the real web and it worked quite well.

Comment: IT still works great, thx